# Ionic commands not responding in windows 7

Tags: ionic-framework

I've installed cordova, ionic, phonegap, android-sdk on windows 7. But Ionic is not responding anything when I type `ionic -v` or `ionic start myApp tabs`. I've attached screenshot below :

Underscore is blinking so long time in command prompt and is not responding to any input.

[image]

Comment: Only ionic? are you using PowerShell?

Comment: Other command is alright such as npm -v, cordova -v, java -version. I've tested with PowerShell. But It's not work.

Comment: did you try re-installing? maybe with the console (not the git one)? What about environment variables?